# jQuery: Can't append img tag after .find

Tags: jquery, html, dom, append, image

I have a strange problem happening on one page I am making:

```
myDiv.append("<img src='...' />")            <--- WORKS
myDiv.find("p").append("whatever")         <--- WORKS
myDiv.find("p").append("<img src='...' />")  <--- FAILS!
```

On that last one nothing gets appended. I can't see what is going wrong through Firebug. When I create new test page all three work, but I can't get it to work on the real page. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: it works on a new test page?.. that means we aren't going to be able to re-produce this issue.

Comment: @Fosco is right. See http://jsfiddle.net/J5MSf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah sorry, I found out the problem which was not surprisingly due to conflicting scripts on the page. I had another script which was automatically removing empty elements in the area and apparently it considers img tags to be empty. The reason the first example I gave works is because it placed the images outside the scope that the deletion script was working. Doh.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use find('p').html('...') instead.

I wonder if that works in your case, because I cannot see why there would be any issues.

Comment: The other thing I would look at is the html that is already in the P tag.  Could it be malformed causing the image to not render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have some css that is hiding the image.  Something like

```
p img{
   display: none
}
```

or any number of other styles would cause the issue described and also explain why it works in a separate page.  I would suggest inspecting the dom and seeing if the element is in fact there, and if so, trace the style to see what's hiding it.

Comment: No, I've examined the html and no tags are even inserted.